# Retrieve first two parts of single string using MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, string, split

I'm trying to retrieve a string from my MySQL Database, the string looks like this:
`/test/examplepath/userlog.txt`

What I need is just the first two parts of this string (`/test/examplepath`) to be retrieved in a SELECT statement. The second bit is not a set amount either. I have tried using SUBSTRING_INDEX and altering the string to create more unique starting/endpoints. Have also tried CONCAT to join the first part and second part together, but to no avail using SUBSTRING_INDEX to retrieve my data since the forward slashes clash.

Here is an example query I wrote:
`SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '/test/', -1), '/', 1) FROM table WHERE column LIKE '/test%'`. This retrieves the second bit, but I need to join the first bit onto it.

I know that if I was using Ruby or Visual Studio I could split the string or use Regex, but I need to do able to do this within a MySQL query as I need to be able to replicate this for many more strings that may not be `/test/`. Am I using the SUBSTRING incorrectly? Is there a better way to retrieve the `/test/` part and the next part using a CONCAT maybe?

Comment: So the pattern is same i.e. `3 /` in the string ?

Comment: The pattern can have any number of forward slashes in the string. I.e. `/test/` or `/test/example1/example2/example3.txt`

Comment: You want the first two parts and each part is separated with / from another? Am I right? So why not use:
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '/', 2) FROM table WHERE column LIKE '/test%';

Comment: This only bring back `/test` from the strings, not the first and second part that is desired.

Comment: Try `select substring_index(you_column, '/', 3);`

Comment: Just attempted this and this worked, thank you AKJ88 and luoluo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by using suggestion from AKJ88 and clarified by luoluo:

`SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '/', 3) FROM table WHERE column LIKE '/test%'`

Changing the number in the SUBSTRING allowed me to progress through my string further. Thank you to those who contributed.